# Insert Rich Text Editor Record into MySql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to use a rich text editor to insert data into MySQL using PHP. When inserting, however, the PHP code does not recognize the rich text editor.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label>Client Feedback</label>
        <div id="feedback" name="feedback"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#feedback').summernote({
        placeholder: 'Place here the Feedback from the client.',
        tabsize: 1,
    });
</script>


$feedback = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['feedback']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO feedback(InquiryId,FeedBack,DateCreated,DateUpdated) VALUES ('$inquiryId', '$feedback','$createddate','$createddate')";
```

Comment: Post what your html looks like after inserting/appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs of summernote says that you should use `<div>`, but you can use `textarea` instead of `<div>`. So simply change `<div id="feedback" name="feedback"></div>` to `<textarea id="feedback" name="feedback"></textarea>`.

Comment: jagveer Singh -  Thanks a lot. you saved my time. maybe for further clarification when I type 'testing', its save as '<p>testing<br></p>' . please advice how to retrieve as testing not <p>testing<br></p>.

Comment: You can use `strip_tags($text)` .

Answer (score 0):

You need form for this insert.

Try:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and PHP send.php:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['firstname'] == true && $_POST['lastname'] == true)
{
 // Here insert to mysql with $_POST
}
?>
```

look at this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: the form is there only that extracted the div containing rich text editor. but the answer for jagveer Singh sorted me out. otherwise thanks for your humble contribution